# What is the meaning of this poor sequencing result?

Tags: dna-sequencing

What is the meaning of this poor sequencing result? What is the problem?
Can anyone guide me, please. Thank you.
[image: poor sequencing result 1]

[image: poor sequencing result 2]

Comment: It means that your srquencing failed. In my sequencing experience there is nothing so to save here, you simply have to repeat the reaction. What have you exactly done? Are you sure that your primer works on your template?

Comment: Was your template a PCR product or a plasmid ? Have you seen your template DNA on electrophoresis before sequencing ? If yes, was it just one band, or many ?